# Import multiple column families from hbase to hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata

I am trying to move **hbase** table having two **column family** into **hive** table. I am able to move one column family but how can i move another one in same hive table.

**Edit:**

I moved one column family ushing below code.

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_hive(key string, firstname string, age string)
STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (“hbase.columns.mapping” = “id:firstname,id:age")
TBLPROPERTIES(“hbase.table.name” = “hl”);
```

but i am having one more column family with name `hb` and having three columns. How to achive this.

**Update:**

I also tried adding column name of different column family below is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_hive(key string, firstname string, age string, testname string)
STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (“hbase.columns.mapping” = “id:firstname,id:age,pd:name")
TBLPROPERTIES(“hbase.table.name” = “hl”);
```

but i am getting below result:

```
 819215975  19391121    625678921720    NULL
 819617215  19570622    625116365890    NULL
 820333876  19640303    623221670810    NULL
 824794938  19531211    625278010070    NULL
 828093442  19420803    625284904860    NULL
 828905771  19320209    625078004220    NULL
 829832017  19630722    625178010070    NULL
```

Instead of values i am getting null.

**Update:**

I tried creating hbase table using below command in hbase shell

```
create ‘hl’,’id’
```

then i created one more column family using below command

```
alter ‘hl’,’pd’
```

Comment: it's easier if you show some sample code or how you achieved moving the first cf

Comment: @Gevorg i have updated my question. please check.

Answer (score 0):

In your HiveQL, you select two columns in column family "id" from hbase table "hl" into hive table. If you want to add more columns (even from other column families), you just need to add them to table schema and `hbase.columns.mapping`. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_hive(key string, firstname string, age string, a string)
STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (“hbase.columns.mapping” = “id:firstname,id:age,hb:a")
TBLPROPERTIES(“hbase.table.name” = “hl”);
```

see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-MultipleColumnsandFamilies

Comment: i tried this but the other column from different column family is showing `NULL` values only but in hbase i can see there is data in that column.

Comment: @animal are you sure `hb` is a column family and stored in `hl` table? could you provide more information like the output of `describe "hl"`

Comment: cannot know what's wrong based on your information. I wonder how you store your data in hbase.

Comment: i created it properly as i can see the results in hive table when i am storing columns of a particular column family. While joining two different column family i am getting `Null`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues (more or less serious) with what you wrote:

- First of all, I would create an `EXTERNAL TABLE` instead
- You are creating a Hive table with only 3 columns but expecting 4 in the end
- You are not explicitly mapping the `:key`
- Your data for 'firstname' and 'age' looks like wild random numbers! :|

I could not test it but the following should be a better starting point:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_hive_hl(key string, firstname string, age string, name string)
STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (“hbase.columns.mapping” = “:key,id:firstname,id:age,pd:name")
TBLPROPERTIES(“hbase.table.name” = “hl”);
```

Comment: i tried this way but i am getting the last coloumn values as `Null`

Comment: did you try exactly that? Note that it's different from what you wrote in your question. If so, then please update your question with the script used to create the HBase table and the exact query that you used to generate your sample output. Also, make sure to drop the existing hbase_hive table before trying other stuff